# Как обработать по 1 миллион строк в 100 потоков?

Tags: node.js, worker-threads

У меня в бд есть 1 млн строк. Мне нужно их обработать в 100 потоков.
Я решил использовать модуль `worker_threads`.

```
const ServerWorkers = [];
for (let index = 0; index < servers.length; index++) {
    const server = servers[index];

    const ip = server[0];
    const threads = server[1];

    for (let thread = 1; thread <= threads; thread++) {
        const worker = new Worker('./worker.js', {
            workerData: ip
        });
        ServerWorkers.push(worker);
    }
}
console.log(`Создано ServerWorkers: ${ServerWorkers.length}`)
```

У меня создается 100 воркеров.

Далее мне нужно получить из БД строки которые нужно обрабатывать.

Но получать 1 млн строк - я думаю это очень сильно нагрузит систему. Поэтому я бы хотел получать порционно по 1000 строк, обрабатывать их воркерами и получать следующую 1000 строк. и так по кругу.

Не понимаю как организовать порционную выборку строк и как их передавать воркерам по очереди (свободным).

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Вот такой функцией я могу взять 1000 строк:

```
async function getOrdersForChecked(task, limit) {
    let getEmails = await client.query({
        query: `SELECT email FROM orders WHERE id_task = ${task} AND checked = 0 ORDER BY id_task LIMIT ${limit}`,
        format: 'JSONEachRow',
    });
    getEmails = await getEmails.json();

    return getEmails;
}
```

Comment: Если есть нормальный первичный ключ, то отсортировать по нему `ORDER BY id` получить его `SELECT id, email` а в следующих итерациях добавлять условие для продолжения `WHERE id > последний id из предыдущей итерации`

Comment: (Если нет нормального первичного ключа, то страдать и хорошенько подумать о его добавлении)

Comment: 100 воркеров не многовато ли будет? Это потенциальное использование 100CPU для интенсивных операций. Если из БД выбирается только одно поле, то можно и всю таблицу выбрать.

Comment: @SwaD одно поле. А что если 10 млн строк будет?

Comment: Тогда это будет уже второй вопрос :) Хороший вариант с первичным ключом, описан выше. Так же можно создать в БД процедурку, которая будет отбирать записи, как то их метить и возвращать набор данных в ноду, это поможет уйти от сортировки большой таблицы. Допустим создаете поле isUpdated, перед началом его апдейтите в 0. Далее делаете выборку 1000 записей, проставляете им флаг, допустим 1 и возвращаете. Следующий вызов процедуры уже эти записи не возьмет. Если за данными будут ходить несколько инстансов, то выборку можно организовать с `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`

Comment: а сколько времени занимает обработка в один поток? (скажем, чанками по 1000, ну или всего миллиона)

Comment: Вы не указали СУБД и не знаю, есть ли метод в библиотеке, однако, если можно читать данные из таблицы построчно, то можно вычитать первую пачку данных и отправить в воркер, далее вычитать вторую пачку и отправить в воркер, если воркеры заняты, не вычитывать, как воркер освободится, следующую пачку считать и отправить